# Can WebDataBinder#getObjectName() return null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

I extends

```
public class RenamingProcessor extends ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor {
        @Override
        protected void bindRequestParameters(WebDataBinder binder,     NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest) {
            ...    
            binder.getObjectName();
            ...
        }
}
```

Can `binder.getObjectName()` returns null?

I tried to research source but I didn't find  this information in javadoc?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't return null (in this statement i assume spring framework is not broken).

First off, WebDataBinder will always have a value. Looking at the [ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor implementation of bindRequestParameters](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java#ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters%28org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder%2Corg.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest%29)  they use `WebDataBinder binder` as is :

```
ServletRequestDataBinder servletBinder = (ServletRequestDataBinder) binder;
//No null check between cast and usage
servletBinder.bind(servletRequest);
```

It does not matter which constructor is used to build the WebDataBinder which you receive. Of the 2 available on [WebDataBinder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.2.5/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.java#WebDataBinder.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%29):

```
1.    public WebDataBinder(Object target);
2.    public WebDataBinder(Object target, String objectName);
```

The second is obvious will have an objectName  - in the sense that i don't believe any sane programmer working on spring will call this with a null value.

The first one calls the [DataBinder constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.context/3.2.5/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.java#DataBinder.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.Object%29) which calls the constructor with the objectName ( public DataBinder(Object target, String objectName)), except with a default objectName:

```
this(target, DEFAULT_OBJECT_NAME);
```

which is

```
public static final String DEFAULT_OBJECT_NAME = "target";
```

There is no setter for the objectName. Once initialized, it will keep having a value.

Sidenote: **the target attribute (`getTarget()`) can have a null value** if the the binder is just used to convert a plain parameter value. Not sure about the application for this tho.

---

**Update**: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33222457/4807777) cleared up [my question on How is Spring's DataBinder used to convert a plain parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103045/how-is-springs-databinder-used-to-convert-a-plain-parameter-value).

Comment: **if the the binder is just used to convert a plain parameter value.**  Please clarify this statement?

Comment: I only mentioned it because i saw it in the docs of the WebDataBinder's parent class, DataBinder and i found it interesting. I've actually looked but haven't seen any such usage and am actually curious myself how else would you use the databinder, probably with just a few methods as utilities. Anyways, feel free to ask another question on this, It can make for an interesting one.

Comment: I actually asked a question on this myself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103045/how-is-springs-databinder-used-to-convert-a-plain-parameter-value

Comment: I follow your question). Actually I was asked in code review to check on NPE result of getObjectName

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33222457/4807777 cleared up the matter for me