# How is Spring's DataBinder used to convert a plain parameter value?

Tags: java, spring, data-binding

I've been digging through the Spring DataBinder [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.java#DataBinder) and [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html) while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101031/can-webdatabindergetobjectname-return-null)  and i've noticed the [DataBinder constructor docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#DataBinder-java.lang.Object-) mentionioning :

> target - the target object to bind onto (or null if the binder is just
>   used to convert a plain parameter value)

I've been searching around and haven't found such a usage and it really made me curious. Would appreciate any insight related to :

- How would such a data binder be used with a null target to convert a plain parameter value?
- Or what does it actually mean to convert a plain parameter value in this context?
- Is it also applicable to Spring MVC? (since i noticed it mentioned in WebDataBinder's constructor docs as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been done some digging in the Spring Framework source, searching for usages with null parameter as you described. Since I was not aware of this kind of usage either, looking at the testcases to understand things better was my way to go.

The test class for `DataBinder` is (not surprisingly) `DataBinderTests`.

I am going to paste a usage example here, along with the link to github where I found the code, for reference:

For your first question, the answer seems if you use a `DataBinder` with `null` constructor parameter, it means that you just want to use the conversion facility, without the data binding mechanism (since we have not passed an object to bind values to).
This pretty explanatory testcase shows this type of usage, creating a `DataBinder` with `null`, setting a `DefaultFormattingConversionService` to the `dataBinder` and registering a custom editor after that. 
You can add a custom converter with the `addConverter` method if you want a different String representation after converting your bean.

```
    @Test
    public void testConversionWithInappropriateStringEditor() {
        DataBinder dataBinder = new DataBinder(null);
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        dataBinder.setConversionService(conversionService);
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));

        NameBean bean = new NameBean("Fred");
        assertEquals("ConversionService should have invoked toString()", "Fred", dataBinder.convertIfNecessary(bean, String.class));
        conversionService.addConverter(new NameBeanConverter());
        assertEquals("Type converter should have been used", "[Fred]", dataBinder.convertIfNecessary(bean, String.class));
    }
```

For reference, here is the code of `NameBeanConverter` (also from the test class)

```
public static class NameBeanConverter implements Converter<NameBean, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(NameBean source) {
        return "[" + source.getName() + "]";
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d5ee787e1e6653257720afe31ee3f8819cd4605c/spring-context/src/test/java/org/springframework/validation/DataBinderTests.java#L598-L609

I think the above explanation was an answer for the first two questions:

> How would such a data binder be used with a null target to convert a plain parameter value?
>   Or what does it actually mean to convert a plain parameter value in this context?

For your third question, unfortunately, I have not found any usable testcase like above, but going through the `WebDataBinder`'s code make me think of there is no "added value" compared to `DataBinder` in terms of a null constructor parameter, so you can use the conversion facility through the `WebDataBinder` as well.

You probably know that you can bind your web request fields to your backing bean, adding conversion (e.g. converting a particularly formatted date to an actual `Date` field object on the backing bean) etc etc, but I don't want to describe this in more detail as this was not your point with the question I guess.

Lastly, I found this article very useful about how the `WebDataBinder` could be used: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-frameworks-webdatabinder/

Answer (score 1):

You can think of DataBinder as filter or handler that all request parameters go  thorough before they get consumed. To make use of the DataBinder functionality you need to implement a method in your controller class with "**@InitBinder**" annotation. For example:

```
 @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
        // bind empty strings as null
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }
```

As you see, all you need to do in the method is register **CustomEditor** for a specific data type.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC, a DataBinder with a null target  is automatically used in a case like this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHome(@RequestParam("date") Date date) {

    return "home";
}
```

In this case, the created DataBinder has an objectName  "date" and a null target.